# How to make this repetitive Update statement in MySQL shorter?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Update statement in MySQL which updates multiple columns using select statements.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET ColumnA =
(
    SELECT TableB.ColumnA
    FROM TableB
    WHERE (TableB.ColumnX = 0 AND TableB.id = TableA.fk_id)
)
,ColumnB =
(
    SELECT TableB.ColumnB
    FROM TableB
    WHERE (TableB.ColumnX = 0 AND TableB.id = TableA.fk_id)
)
,ColumnC =
(
    SELECT TableB.ColumnC
    FROM TableB
    WHERE (TableB.ColumnX = 0 AND TableB.id = TableA.fk_id)
)
```

It works fine and is simple to understand. However, it violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. The WHERE clause repeats. It does not look good in a code review exercise. How to rewrite this MySQL statement in a manner which does not violate the DRY principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b
       ON b.ColumnX = 0 AND b.id = a.fk_id
   SET a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA, a.ColumnB = b.ColumnB, a.ColumnC = b.ColumnC;
```

MySQL update syntax allows to combine mutiple tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html